# Meteor: Force user logout on server-side

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

The users in my Meteor application need a verified email address to login. When a user changes his email address I want to log him out on the serverside and send a new verification email.

I am already deleting the `login.resume.tokens`, but that is not killing the user session (he gets logged out on page reload). So how kann I kill the users session on the serverside? Are there more things to delete?
I want the browser to realize reactively that the current session has been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use "[currentUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser)".  It is reactive, and when the token gets deleted on the server side it will return null.

```
{{#if currentUser }}
  <!--  template here  -->
{{/if}}
```

Comment: This cannot be the case, because after I delet the tokens on the server, my client still has the Meteor.user object in the global scope, since this is not null, the currentUser-helper will still return true...

Comment: I just tried it out and it logged out my user? (returned null, thus not allowing whatever template that is within it to be displayed)  I deleted the token by setting it to null `db.users.update({"_id" : "Ym7mk45DMbvSd5ND4"},{ $unset: {'services.resume.loginTokens.0': 1} });` and then by removing it `db.users.update({"_id" : "Ym7mk45DMbvSd5ND4"},{ $pull: {'services.resume.loginTokens': null} })`

Comment: I just did exactly the same in my command window with meteor mongo and again I'm not logged out directly... only after reloading my browser. Are you having a hosted app in which you tried it out, what could be the reason for the different behaviour?

Comment: I have another Meteor application in which the things you described just worked... this is strange...

Comment: My app is running on localhost.  In my javascript browser console, when I run `Meteor.user();` after unsetting the token, I am still logged in.  But when I **pull** the token, that's when `Meteor.user();` returns null.  I'm using **meteor 1.3.1**

Answer (score 0):

You can track a user status with Tracker & autorun, as so:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    if (! Meteor.userId() && ! Meteor.loggingIn()) // do something here;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the server-side `Meteor.call('logout')` to work for me.  However, I cannot find documentation for it.

And for a reactive variable on the client try using `Meteor.userId()` e.g. inside of an autorun like `Meteor.autorun(function(){...});`.

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem to be documented, but did you try `Accounts.logout()` on the server? Looks like [it's implemented](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L529). Otherwise just run `Accounts.logout()` on the client after the change. I think in your case that's acceptable.

Comment: No thats unfortunately not acceptable... the user should not be able to do anything in the name of this user, until the new email has been verified. Also the Accounts.logout() method is undefined on the server...